# PHP Update/Row edit with MySQL

Tags: php, set, edit

So I've been working on a nation simulator game. Its gonna be online and I have a lot of experience with CSS and HTML, but not with PHP. I also have a lot of experience with Java and C++. I have the data base setup and working with a functioning login and register system, along with a functioning member index displaying the nations current stats. However, I have been completely unable to figure out how to make a script that would change user information such as nation name and current funds available. This is my feeble attempt at one: (It's attempting to add 10 buildings to the total. SESS_ are variables in a session)

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Include database connection details
require_once('config.php');

//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}


$result = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET buildings ='10' WHERE login='SESS_NATION'") 
or die(mysql_error());  


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE login='SESS_NATION'") 
or die(mysql_error());  

// get the first (and hopefully only) entry from the result
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
echo $row['login']." - ".$row['Buildings']. "<br />";
?>
```

Comment: is SESS_NATION a name or constant..?

Comment: SESS_NATION is declared as a constant in another file, login-exec.php.

Answer (score 1):

If your variables are in session, try:

```
//or if a constant then,
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET buildings ='10' WHERE login='".SESS_NATION."'") 
or die(mysql_error());  

//first one
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET buildings ='10' WHERE login='".$_SESSION['SESS_NATION']."'") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Just to add on to this, you will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks without sanitizing the session variable. Use mysql_real_escape_string().

Also, I strongly suggest using an active record library like http://www.phpactiverecord.org to simplify your work. You'll thank yourself later.

Comment: I tried both and I got an error saying "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /www/clanteam.com/n/a/t/nationtrial/htdocs/PHP-Login/inf.php on line 29"

Comment: Check edit above, if SESS_NATION is a constant and accessible in the file you are using UPDATE code, then it should work... Hope it helps